# cygcheck could not find 'curl'

Tags: curl, cygwin

I have used Cygwin Package Manager to install curl with no issues.  I can call up the manual for curl using the man curl command.  However, when I try cygcheck curl I get "cygcheck: could not find 'curl'".  When I try
curl https://stats.wikimedia.org/EN/TablesWikipediaZZ.htm
I get "-bash: curl: command not found"
cygcheck chmod works.  There is no curl.exe file in my cygwin64\bin folder.
I have Windows 7.
I also tried using Cygwin Package Manager with src? selected for curl.  This did not have any effect - I still get could not find 'curl'.

Any ideas as to how to get curl to work?

Comment: what is the output of `cygcheck -c curl` ?

Comment: Check your virus scanner status. It may have quarantined the exe.

Comment: In reply to matzeri  the output of `cygcheck -c curl` is status incomplete.  In reply to Doug - Thank you, spot on, I found it there and have restored so now all is good.